# how to merge two columns in a csv and combining them in list formate and put comma between merged value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am working on a pandas data frame where I want to `merge two columns` and putting a comma `,` between those values which are merged and then add the whole cell by `[]`.

Example:
I have this kind of data frame: **note:** The sample data is uploaded on this **[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bfjEa3RKcVExQICAXhcL97jTz_p0J2tE/view?usp=sharing)**

```
 bboxes                                             class_names      
 [[0,0,2336,2836],[0,0,2336,2836],[0,0,2336,2836]]  ['No finding','No finding','No finding']
```

and I want to merge two `col` and add comma between the content `,` then enclosed that merge `col` by `[]` like below:

```
                                             final_bboxes    
    [[[0,0,2336,2836],[0,0,2336,2836],[0,0,2336,2836]],['No finding','No finding','No finding']]
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to convert the list as strings to an actual list before combining them. I have used `ast.literal_eval` to do this safely.

```
import ast


df["final_bboxes"] = df.apply(lambda row: [ast.literal_eval(row["bboxes"]), ast.literal_eval(row["class_names"])], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I don't understand what's happing internally but its work,
Appreciate Please upvote my question someone downgrade my `reputation` :(

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks for accepting. I had to use `literal_eval` because the values of columns `bboxes` and `class_names` are strings even though they look like list. I had to convert them to list first. And you can check doc of `df.apply` function [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
df['new_col'] = [[x,y] for [x,y] in df[['bboxes', 'class_names']].values]
```

## string/quote issue

```
df['new_col'] = [[eval(x),eval(y)] for [x,y] in df[['bboxes', 'class_names']].values]  ## you can use ast modules literal_eval as well
#I am not a fan of eval tbh, don't use it unless you don't have any other way
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it work well but it give me this output 
`['[[0, 0, 2336, 2836], [0, 0, 2336, 2836], [0, 0, 2336, 2836]]', "['No finding', 'No finding', 'No finding']"]` and I don't want to include the double qotes at start and end of list.

The above answer work well
Thanks
Please upvote my question someone devoted I don't know why? :( I ask a real problem working in a project

Comment: Yes, you can use eval method to avoid the strings/quotes, but my advise "try to avoid it". Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks, you sir both answers solve my problem hats off to you.
yes, you are right. I check the time complexity and your method took less time.
Thanks again